# DynamoDB, BatchWriteItem for an array - AWS V3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an array I am using to create a put for batchwriteitem.

```
   const people = [{
        location: 'London',
        name: 'Tony Wilson',
        pets:  [ {name: 'Cuddles', age: 4}, { name: 'Jess', age: 2}]
    },
        {
            location: 'Manchester',
            name: 'Liz Smith',
            pets:  [ {name: 'Fluffy', age: 4}, { name: 'Keith the cat', age: 2}]
        }
    ]
```

My batchwriteitem loop is working for individual items

```
 location: { S : item.location },
```

but when I try and input the pets array as an array it fails

```
 pets: { M:  item.pets },
```

So this all works except the pets array.

```
 const request = pets.map(item => {
        const createdDate = Date.now();
        return {
            PutRequest: {
                Item: {   
                  location: { S : item.location },
                  createdDate:{ N: createdDate },
                  pets: { M:  item.pets }
               }
            }
        });
```

Do I need to break down the pets array into types and if so how can I achieve this?

Edit

```
pets: { L:  item.pets }, does not work
```

**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

and the old syntax without the types does not work on v3 with the document client for me.

Answer (score 0):

Pets is an array, which is also known as a list type. You are setting it as a dictionary/map type as you've set the value to `M`. It should be `L`:

```
pets: { L:  item.pets },
```

I would advise that you use the [Document Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html) as it means you do not need to think about the type conversions, and just use native JSON objects:

```
pets: item.pets,
```

Comment: I need to insert multiple items can I do this with doc client? It does seem much easier.

Comment: Yes, use BatchWriteItem just as before: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property